# LWC Apex Class not being fired

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a LWC button that runs some validations, if there are no validations then the code should submit for approval. The validation code is working however the apex code is not firing for some reason.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import SubmitQuoteForApproval from '@salesforce/apex/lwcSubmitQuoteForApproval.SubmitForApproval';
const FIELDS = ['SBQQ__Quote__c.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c','SBQQ__Quote__c.Special_Lines_Roll_UP__c', 'SBQQ__Quote__c.Discount_Explanation__c'];
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';


//validatation show on Screen 
//Need to figure out how to display message from JS to HTML 
//IF there is a validation dont run code. 
//If no validation display Toast Message and close window and refresh page
//Can Display Toast notification and close window 
export default class lwcSubmitQuoteForApproval extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
quote;
SBQQ__LineItemCount__c;
Special_Lines_Roll_UP__c;
Discount_Explanation__c;
ValidationMessage;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
wiredRecord({error, data }) {

    if(data) {
        this.quote = data;
        this.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c = this.quote.fields.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c.value;
        this.Special_Lines_Roll_UP__c = this.quote.fields.Special_Lines_Roll_UP__c.value;
        this.Discount_Explanation__c = this.quote.fields.Discount_Explanation__c.value;
        //Must declare that ValidationMessage be nothing. 
        this.ValidationMessage  = '';

        if(this.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c == 0){
            this.ValidationMessage = this.ValidationMessage +  'Wait a Second! This Particular Quote has no Quote Line items.\n'; 
            
        }

        if(this.Special_Lines_Roll_UP__c == 0){
            this.ValidationMessage = this.ValidationMessage +  'Wait a Second! This Particular Quote has some Special line items which are rejected.\n';
           
        }

        if (this.ValidationMessage == ''){
            SubmitQuoteForApproval, ({idQuote:'$recordId' })
           
            this.showErrorToast("Quote has successfully been submitted")
            this.closeAction() 
        }


    }
}

closeAction(){
   this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
}
  
  showErrorToast(x) {
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Toast Message',
        message: x,
        variant: 'Success',
        mode: 'dismissable'
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }  
}
```

Apex Class

```
public with sharing class lwcSubmitQuoteForApproval {


public lwcSubmitQuoteForApproval() {
    system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'Start lwcSubmitQuoteForApproval');
}
@AuraEnabled
public static void SubmitForApproval(id IDQuote){

    system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'Start SubmitForApproval          ' + idQuote);
    
    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
    req1.setComments('');
    req1.setObjectId(IDQuote);
    Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);


}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple typo.

```
SubmitQuoteForApproval, ({idQuote:'$recordId' })
```

should be:

```
SubmitQuoteForApproval({idQuote:'$recordId' })
```

The original syntax doesn't produce an error, it just does nothing, as the comma operator just evaluates each side and then returns the value on the right. See the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) for more information.

Comment: wow..... your right. it was a simple typo

Comment: I know that this is probably a separate question however the ID isnt passing to the apex class correctly. Its coming over as null... Any ideas?

Comment: @CodeMonger JavaScript is case sensitive. You named it `IDQuote` in apex, but `idQuote` in your LWC code. Make them match, it should work fine.